# Linux/Unix - /etc/sudoers - host definition

Tags: linux, unix, sudo, host

can anybody tell me in which case the sudo host definition is useful?

I mean this part of a line in the sudoers file:

```
bob host1 = NOPASSWD: reboot
```

In which environment (except `sudo` via LDAP) do I need to define the host on which a user can run the specified command?

Answer (score 8):

Here are some things I can think of:-

- You deploy sudoers via a central source using some configuration management system.
- The file exists on an NFS share mounted by multiple hosts.
- A particular system uses many `UTS` namespaces (different containers have different hostnames)
- You may intend a particular set of permissions on a particular hostname (which represents a role of a system such as a webserver). But you later change the hostname as it changes roles, this removes `sudo` capabilities for users with a hostname listed.